# How to create an Applet that creates drop-downs that pull from Oracle database

Tags: java, database, swing, applet

Here is my current program:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Properties;

public class CodesApplet extends Applet 
{
    private Properties properties;
    private String configFilePath;
    private FileInputStream fis;
    private String driverName;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String url;

    private Connection conn;
    private Statement st;
    private Timestamp created = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

    private JComboBox codes1;
    private JComboBox codes2;
    private JComboBox otherCodes;

    public void init() 
    {
        try 
        {
            //Loads the values from the properties file 
            try 
            {
                properties = new Properties();
                configFilePath="C:\\scriptProps.properties";
                fis = new FileInputStream(configFilePath);

                properties.load(fis);

                if (fis != null)
                {
                    fis.close();
                }
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                System.err.println("init(): FileNotFoundException(): " + e.getMessage());
            }

            driverName=properties.getProperty("driverName");
            userName=properties.getProperty("userName");
            password=properties.getProperty("password");
            url=properties.getProperty("url");

            //Establishes the connection to the database
            System.out.println("init(): loading OracleDriver for applet created at " + created.toString());
            Class.forName(driverName);
            System.out.println("init(): getting connection");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            st = conn.createStatement();

            //Instantiates the previously declared variables for the drop-downs.
            codes1 = new JComboBox();
            codes2 = new JComboBox();
            otherCodes = new JComboBox();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.err.println("init(): ClassNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.err.println("init(): SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("init(): IOException. " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void start() 
    {
        System.out.println("start(): ");
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        System.out.println("stop(): ");
    }

    //Returns the first drop-down...
    public JComboBox getComboBox1() 
    {
        codes1.removeAllItems();
        codes1.addItem("Please Select...");

        try 
        {
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select codes from myTable");

            while (rs.next()) 
            {
                codes1.addItem(rs.getString("codes"));
            }

            rs.close();
            st.close();
        } 
        catch (SQLException sqle)
        {
            System.out.println(sqle);
        }

        return codes1;
    }

    //Returns the second drop-down...
    public JComboBox getComboBox2() 
    {
        codes2.removeAllItems();
        codes2.addItem("Please Select...");

        try 
        {
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select codes from myTable");

            while (rs.next()) 
            {
                codes2.addItem(rs.getString("codes"));
            }

            rs.close();
            st.close();
        } 
        catch (SQLException sqle)
        {
            System.out.println(sqle);
        }

        return codes2;
    }

    //Returns the third drop-down...
    public JComboBox getComboBox3() 
    {
        otherCodes.removeAllItems();
        otherCodes.addItem("Please Select...");

        try 
        {
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select otherCodes from myTable2");

            while (rs.next()) 
            {
                otherCodes.addItem(rs.getString("otherCodes"));
            }

            rs.close();
            st.close();
        } 
        catch (SQLException sqle)
        {
            System.out.println(sqle);
        }

        return otherCodes;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        System.out.println("paint(): creating the drop-downs...");

        getComboBox1();
        getComboBox2();
        getComboBox3();
    }

    public void destroy() 
    {
        System.out.println("destroy(): closing connection for applet created at " + created.toString());

        try 
        {
            conn.close();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("destroy: SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, what I want to do is have this applet that pulls data from multiple tables and populates drop-down boxes with that data. I've seen some examples on how to do this with one drop-down (thus why you see one return statement involving codes1).

My primary questions are:

- In general, am I doing this right? Is this the best way to pull in multiple fields from multiple tables?

  Also, I understand that this would only populate the combo boxes. If I wanted to allow the user to hit a button after selecting the appropriate values from the drop-downs (after they've been populated), and store those values to a separate table in the database, how would I do that?

Comment: See [*What Applets Can and Cannot Do*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) and try to focus on a single question. A custom tutorial is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: @trashgod okay so I shortened my number of questions to two. But based on your comment, are you trying to say an applet can't do what I want it to do?

Comment: It looks like a _signed_ applet can do this, but I'd prefer a [tag:javawebstart] application. A complete design is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad, but this is really not right: public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        System.out.println("paint(): creating the drop-downs...");

        getComboBox1();
        getComboBox2();
        getComboBox3();
    } You hardly ever need to override paint. Instead create your combo boxes when applet starts and upon some user input event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many problems in your applet:

- You never add your comboboxes to a top-level container hierarchy
- You can add [ActionListener to the JComboBoxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners) if you want to be notified of user selection changes
- You should not override paint
- You are recreating the content of your comboboxes everytime paint is called. You should rather create and add your comboboxes upon applet initalization
- Applet are usually distributed through web pages/server: your propery file won't be available
- Unless your database allow remote access, this will not work.
- To add a button to the display, simply call new JButton("My button") and add it to the component hierarchy
- ...

Here is a link to [Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html). I think that many chapters can help you

Comment: @Guillaume Polet Haha, yikes. Did not think I was that far off with my code. I was reading around, do you think instead of going this route, it might be a better idea to look at using JSP and creating a custom JSP tag?

Comment: @This0nePr0grammer this might be an option, yes (although I doubt you need to create custom JSP tags). There are other Java open sources alternatives, like GWT, JFace (the evolution of JSP, I think), ... Really impossible to tell without knowing the context. You need to evaluate your needs and constraints, and based on that choose the appropriate solution. But I think that these questions are not meant for SO, but rather programmer-exchange, or another stack-exchange Q&A